# ignoring, hidding mu plugins when wp-cli is run

Tags: wp-cli, mu-plugins

`wp-cli` & a `mu plugin` don't get along causing the following error:

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function getAdminOptions() on null in
>   /wp-content/mu-plugins/mobile-smart-proMU.php"

Line of code causing the problem is:

```
$options = $mobile_smart->getAdminOptions();
```

I have reached out to plugin developer and for the time being, I have changed the `mu-plugins` folder to `mu-plugins-old`. I am Wondering if there is a way to set a exclude rule in `config.yml` for `mu plugins`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of Mobile Smart Pro. I'm in the midst of testing WP-CLI with Mobile Smart Pro, and on line 27 of /wp-content/mu-plugins/ you should add the following test:

`if (!$mobile_smart) return $pluginList;`

So the section would look like:

`function disablePlugins($pluginList) {

```
    if (is_admin()) return $pluginList; // only deactivate on front end

    global $mobile_smart;

    if (!$mobile_smart) return $pluginList;

    // get options
    $options = $mobile_smart->getAdminOptions();
```

I'll be releasing an update for this today, but wanted to respond on here for you too.

Dan